# How to compute the derivative of this implicit function?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $y=y(x)$ is an implicit function given by equation $y-$sin$y=x$, and I was asked to solve out $y'''(\pi)$.

I know using chain rules can give a bunch of equations, but it seems too complicated for me to work out relations betweem them. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: You must have tried at least _something_.  Perhaps include that in your post.

Answer (score 3):

Given the relation $y-\sin y=x$, we have

\begin{align}
y-\sin y&=x\\
\frac{dy}{dx}-\cos y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}&=1\\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cos y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)&=0\\
&\vdots\\
\left.\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}\right|_{x=\pi}&=\cdots
\end{align}

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I know how to write down these equations, but I don't know how to simplify them and get the result.

Comment: You will get an equation $y'''$ in terms of $y'', y', $ and $y$.  Use the earlier equations to write $y'''$ in terms of $y$ only.